# Open multiple browser tabs from a single button click: ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have following VB code is expecting open 2 tabs simultaneously when condition is true. But unfortunately it is opening first tab and second one is not opening. Please advice

```
If m_strIdNumber <> 0 AndAlso UserValNum <> 0 Then
        ' is working 
        Dim url As String = MainURL + "?qs=" + m_strIdNumber + "&usr=" + "local"
        Dim script As String = String.Format("window.open('{0}');", url)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "newPage" + UniqueID, script, True)

        ' But this is not working 
        Dim url1 As String = MainURL + "?qs=" + UserValNum + "&usr=" + "local"
        Dim script As String = String.Format("window.open('{0}');", url1)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "newPage" + UniqueID, script, True)
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy(v=vs.110).aspx) "Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page."

So you need to give both calls of RegisterStartupScript a unique key. For example

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "newPage1" + UniqueID, script, True)
' ...
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "newPage2" + UniqueID, script, True)
```